# direct3d9 how to filter texture for pixel art

Tags: c++, directx, pixel, direct3d9

hello i want to make pixel art image looks less blurry i tried set sampler state but i see no difference

```
device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

[image]

i tried almost everything in setsamplerstate but i see no difference at all

i know i can make the photo bigger using photoshop but can i just make it looks hard edge with direct3d9

Comment: Does it help if you change `D3DTEXF_NONE` to `D3DTEXF_POINT`?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: This seems to be a good summary of the texture filtering options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/texture-filtering

Comment: that's what i tried

Comment: quick question, is your texture loading and has MIP levels implemented?  This may explain the bluriness, even when using point sampling.

Answer (score 1):

"Pixel art" is typically drawn without any blending or bi-linear filtering. For legacy Direct3D 9, you'd use (assuming your textures are bound to slot 0):

```
device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

> At this point, you shouldn't use legacy Direct3D 9 at all. Direct3D 11 is your best bet. If you are using C++, take a look at the [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch) class with the [CommonStates::PointClamp()](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/CommonStates) sampler state in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: still don't work for me
and i don't use Direct3D 11 because i can't find much good tutorials about it

Comment: The internet is full of good tutorials on Direct3D 11. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/).

Comment: Tutorials wise, look up Rastertek as its a great resource for C++ DX 11 examples.